# Why Isn't Using Namespaces for Autoloading Bad Practice?

Tags: php, namespaces, autoloader, psr-0

I've seen a bunch of examples using PSR to do autoloading with namespaces. Maybe this is a dumb question, but why isn't this bad practice? Doesn't that defeat the purpose of having namespaces?

For example, say you have two libraries, `FormBuilder` and `MySweetForms`, and both have a `Form` class. Locations are at:

`lib/FormBuilder/Core/Form.php` and `lib/MySweetForms/Form.php`

If you autoload based on the namespaces those `Form` classes are in, aren't you going to run into the exact problem that namespaces are meant to prevent: ambiguous identifiers of classes and methods?

Won't it fail when you successfully locate another class in the `MySweetForms` namespace, say `AjaxFileField`, that relies on `\MySweetForms\Form`, but it finds the `FormBuilder`'s implementation of the `Form` class?

Comment: good question.....interested to hear the answers too! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of namespaces, the autoloading won't find the `FormBuilder`'s implementation of the `Form` class when it's looking for the `MySweetForms` implementation, provided the autoloader and the two libraries follow best (or close to best) practices and are implemented correctly.

If the `MySweetForms/AjaxFileField.php` file defines a class inside the `MySweetForms` namespace as shown:

```
namespace MySweetForms;

class AjaxFileField
{
    public function doFormStuff()
    {
        $form = new Form();
    }
}
```

Then the reference to the `Form` class inside `AjaxFileField` is really a short-hand for the fully qualified class name `MySweetForms\Form`.

When the autoloader is invoked to load the class, it will be asked to load the class based on it's fully qualified name. A PSR-0 autoloader would translate the `MySweetForms\Form` classname into the `MySweetForms/Form.php` path, and (provided it was told to look in the `lib` directory) it would find it's way to the correct file. If that file was missing, the autoloader would ultimately fail. Similarly, if that file defined a `Form` class but neglected to supply a namespace the actual class (`MySweetForms\Form`) would not exist (instead, a global class `Form` would) -- that doesn't match the fully qualified name of the class referred to in the `AjaxFileField` class, so an error would occur.

Note that if the code had included `$form = new \FormBuilder\Core\Form();` instead the class name would already be fully qualified, and the autoloader would be asked to load the `FormBuilder\Core\Form` class (and would expect it to be in the `FormBuilder/Core/Form.php` file).

If we had used `$form = new \Form();` we would be referring to the `Form` class in the global namespace and the autoloader would be asked to find `Form` (it would look in the `Form.php` file directly inside the `lib` folder at this point).

The key is to recognize that there are not, really, two `Form` classes -- there is one class with a fully qualified name of `FormBuilder\Core\Form` and one with a fully qualified name of `MySweetForms\Form` -- and a properly implemented autoloader will expect them in completely different locations, and will not try to load one file in place of the other.

The combination of namespaces and the PSR style of organizing files into directories based on their namespaces makes it very easy to re-use common words without causing conflicts, and to predictably map fully qualified class names to the corresponding files.

The resolution of class names to fully qualified class names is key to this, and is discussed in the PHP manual (the namespace FAQ has a couple of points about it: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php). The PSR-0 standard itself is also a useful reference: https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md